# Why don't I have iPhone native look any more?

Tags: codenameone

At some point I seem to have a lost the ability to go to native iPhone look in the codenameone emulator. How can I get it back to normal?
I did have two themes in the theme.res file - I've tried deleting them both and creating a new native one called "Theme". I've also commented out all my initialization code in the `before` call for the Form, but it still looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Codename One migrated to iOS 7 as required by Apple: http://www.codenameone.com/3/post/2014/01/switching-defaults.html http://www.codenameone.com/3/post/2013/10/seven.html

To use the old simulator for the old theme just select Skins->More and select the old iOS 6 skin. You probably shouldn't though since you need to migrate to iOS 7 which most devices have already migrated to.

Comment: Interesting. My other projects in the same emulator look like os6 though? How can that be?

Comment: Use update client libraries or send a build and that should also update.